# Excel box*x% syntax in IF condition

Tags: excel

I have `IF` condition in which there is expression like this: `A12*1%`

What `*1%` means here ?

Answer (score 1):

It means exactly what it says: "multiplied by 1 percent". It's syntactic sugar for `*0.01`.